# Reading xml content in android

Tags: android

I have an xml file in my Android project.
It contains a simple list of employee ids.
I want to read the below xml content.
I placed this file in `res/raw/`

saplist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EMPNOLIST>
   <EMPID>“12345”</EMPID>
   <EMPID>“23456”</EMPID>
   <EMPID>“34567”</EMPID>
</EMPNOLIST>
```

Code to read it

```
{
   // Load XML for parsing.
   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
   InputStream inputStream = null;
   try {
      inputStream = assetManager.open("saplist.xml");
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
   }
   String s = readTextFile(inputStream);
   Log.e("FMApp: ", s);
}

private String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
   int len;
   try {
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
         outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
      }
      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {

   }
   return outputStream.toString();
}
```

This code doesn't read the xml content.
Instead, it crashes.

Could someone help me on how to read such a simple xml?

Comment: Please post your errors

Comment: If it's in the res folder, you're not going to get it from the assets.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html to read xml data.

Answer (score 0):

You first closed the outputStream and then returned `outputStream.toString()` that isn't going to work.

```
private String readTextFile(InputStream inputStream) {
        String result = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            result = outputStream.toString()
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return result;
    }
```